how to fetch instrumenttype from table the data type for Instruments is row in PostgreSQL
I want to fetch the instrumenttype from instruments column the data sample is
['{instrumenttype=Index}'].
please find attached snap for more details..

I have tried select instruments1.instrumentype from TABLE_NAME;
did not get result.
kindly help me for the same.

You can either use the JSON accessor operator ->>:
SELECT instruments -> 'instrumenttype' FROM tab;

or use this equivalent syntax:
SELECT instruments['instrumenttype'] FROM tab;

Note that the result is of type json or jsonb. If you want the result as a string, either use a type cast or the ->> operator:
SELECT instruments ->> 'instrumenttype' FROM tab;

